# Center circles on page but still overlap slightly

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this is probably simple for those far smarter than I am.  My problem is I want to center the circles in the middle of the page but still keep the slight overlap of each circle.  Everything I try seems to split the circles up and I lose the overlap.  I've tried changing the .ca-menu but what I try doesn't seem to work.  My apologies for all the code, but not sure how to do it without pasting it all.  I wanted to make sure I had everything possibly needed to help find the problem/solution.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: 'Baskerville', 'Palatino Linotype', 'Palatino', 'Century Schoolbook L', 'Times New Roman', 'serif'
}

.homepage {
  background-image: url(pagepics/big_oscar.png), url(pagepics/emmy.png);
  background-position: left, right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 220px, 220px;
  padding: 250px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #4BFC03;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 27.5px;
  color: #d4af37;
}

#header1 {
  width: 1220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 125px;
  background-image: url(pagepics/oscars-banner3.jpg);
}

#header2 {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(pagepics/emmybanner.png);
}

.indent {
  text-indent: 50px;
}

.link1 {
  color: orangered;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #000;
  color: turquoise;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#footer1 {
  color: turquoise;
  text-align: center;
}

img.floatLeft {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

#centerText1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

li h3 {
  margin: .1px 0;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.article:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .3;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(pagepics/emmy.png);
}

.ca-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 140px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ca-menu li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 10px solid orangered;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #005B8E;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 125px;
  transition: all 400ms linear;
}

.ca-menu li a {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #BEFC00;
  position: relative;
}

.ca-icon {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #101254;
  line-height: 135px;
  position: static;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 900ms linear;
}

.ca-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  width: 370px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 20px;
}

.ca-menu li:hover {
  background: #930016;
  border-color: #4BFC03;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon {
  color: #BEFC00;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main {
  display: none;
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub {
  opacity: 8.0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="header1"></div>
</header>

<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
      <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Home Page</strong></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
      <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Oscar Trivia</strong></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
      <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Emmy Trivia</strong></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
      <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Oscar Winners</strong></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
      <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Emmy Winners</strong></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<main>
  <p>
    <h2>Why Are the Academy Awards Statuettes Called "Oscars"?</h2>
    <article>
      <h3 class="indent">blah blah</h3>
      <h3 class="indent">blah blah</h3>
      <h3 class="indent">blah blah</h3>
      <h3 class="indent">blah blah</h3>
    </article>

</main>

<aside>
  <h2>Statistics</h2>
  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li>
      <h3>blah blah</h3>
    </li>
  </ul>

</aside>

<footer>
  <h5 class id="footer1">&copy; BPA Productions 2018</h5>
</footer>
```

Comment: I was playing around with this and thought I'd share it in case any of it helps you see how to do things in different ways. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/r3kjzsrt/ It's responsive but would need additional css to handle mobile screen sizes. Also I didn't work out the centering so the circle menu isn't perfectly centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply wrap them inside a container where you can apply `text-align:center`:

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: 'Baskerville', 'Palatino Linotype', 'Palatino', 'Century Schoolbook L', 'Times New Roman', 'serif'
}

.homepage {
  background-image: url(pagepics/big_oscar.png), url(pagepics/emmy.png);
  background-position: left, right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 220px, 220px;
  padding: 250px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #4BFC03;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 27.5px;
  color: #d4af37;
}

#header1 {
  width: 1220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 125px;
  background-image: url(pagepics/oscars-banner3.jpg);
}

#header2 {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(pagepics/emmybanner.png);
}

.indent {
  text-indent: 50px;
}

.link1 {
  color: orangered;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #000;
  color: turquoise;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#footer1 {
  color: turquoise;
  text-align: center;
}

img.floatLeft {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

#centerText1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

li h3 {
  margin: .1px 0;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.article:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .3;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(pagepics/emmy.png);
}
.menu-container {
  text-align:center;
}
.ca-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width:140px;
}

.ca-menu li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 10px solid orangered;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #005B8E;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 125px;
  transition: all 400ms linear;
}

.ca-menu li a {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #BEFC00;
  position: relative;
}

.ca-icon {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #101254;
  line-height: 135px;
  position: static;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 900ms linear;
}

.ca-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  width: 370px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 20px;
}

.ca-menu li:hover {
  background: #930016;
  border-color: #4BFC03;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon {
  color: #BEFC00;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main {
  display: none;
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub {
  opacity: 8.0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="header1"></div>
</header>
<div class="menu-container">
<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
      <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Home Page</strong></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
      <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Oscar Trivia</strong></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
      <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Emmy Trivia</strong></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
      <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Oscar Winners</strong></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
      <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Emmy Winners</strong></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<main>
  <p>
    <h2>Why Are the Academy Awards Statuettes Called "Oscars"?</h2>
    <article>
      <h3 class="indent">blah blah</h3>
      <h3 class="indent">blah blah</h3>
      <h3 class="indent">blah blah</h3>
      <h3 class="indent">blah blah</h3>
    </article>

</main>

<aside>
  <h2>Statistics</h2>
  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li>
      <h3>blah blah</h3>
    </li>
  </ul>

</aside>

<footer>
  <h5 class id="footer1">&copy; BPA Productions 2018</h5>
</footer>
```

Comment: This centered them but split them up for me on Firefox, which OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast fixed, i thought he don't need to overlap

Comment: I'm using Firefox and it worked perfectly for me.  But I don't understand why. I don't understand why text-align would work for this.

Comment: @BradAnderson because you are using inline-block elemen that behave like text and inline element so you center them like your center text ;) ... only block element can be centred using margin auto

Comment: @TemaniAfif  That makes a little more sense, but I'm still a little lost.  I'm sure the more I play with things, I'll get it figured out.  Thanks so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

A little edited your html code, so it will be better. In CSS, for class `.ca-menu` added `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` for center alignment.

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    font-family:'Baskerville', 'Palatino Linotype', 'Palatino', 'Century Schoolbook L', 'Times New Roman', 'serif'
}

.homepage {
    background-image: url(pagepics/big_oscar.png), url(pagepics/emmy.png);
    background-position: left, right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 220px, 220px;
    padding: 250px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #4BFC03;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 27.5px;
    color: #d4af37;
}

#header1{
    width:1220px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:125px;
    background-image:url(pagepics/oscars-banner3.jpg);
}

#header2{
    width:1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url(pagepics/emmybanner.png);
}

.indent {
    text-indent: 50px;
}

.link1 {
    color: orangered;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #000;
    color: turquoise;
    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#footer1 {
    color: turquoise;
    text-align: center;
}

img.floatLeft {
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}

#centerText1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}

li h3 {
    margin: .1px 0;
}

article {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.article:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: .3;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(pagepics/emmy.png);
}

.ca-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.ca-menu li{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 10px solid orangered;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background: #005B8E;
    margin-right: -26px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 125px;
    transition: all 400ms linear;
}

.ca-menu li a{
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #BEFC00;
    position:relative;
}

.ca-icon{
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #101254;
    line-height: 135px;
    position: static;
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 900ms linear;
}

.ca-content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    width: 370px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 20px;
}

.ca-menu li:hover{
    background: #930016;
    border-color: #4BFC03;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
    color: #BEFC00;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
    display: none;
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub{
    opacity: 8.0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="header1"></div>
</header>

<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
            <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Home Page</strong></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
            <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Oscar Trivia</strong></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
            <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Emmy Trivia</strong></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
            <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Oscar Winners</strong></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
            <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Emmy Winners</strong></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<main><p>
    <h2>Why Are the Academy Awards Statuettes Called "Oscars"?</h2>
    <article><h3 class="indent">blah blah</h3>
        <h3 class="indent">blah blah</h3>
        <h3 class="indent">blah blah</h3>
        <h3 class="indent">blah blah</h3></article>

</main>

<aside>
    <h2>Statistics</h2>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <li><h3>blah blah</h3></li>
    </ul>

</aside>

<footer>
    <h5 class id="footer1">&copy; BPA Productions 2018</h5>
</footer>
```